# Losing decimal value after successive zeros in np array while using vectorize in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Tried using numpy's `vectorize` to vectorize my self-defined ReLU function. Somehow one of my elements in my numpy array with the value 0.5 ends up as 0 after putting it through ReLU function (e.g. max function)

```
def relu_activation(x):
    return max(0,x)
relu = np.vectorize(relu_activation)

z = np.array([0,0,0.5,1])
z = relu(z)
print(z)
```

`print(z)` outputs `[0 0 0 1]` instead of the intended `[0 0 0.5 1]`

When I replaced my vectorised function with a `for` loop, it worked as intended.

Comment: Why not just write a vectorized version of the function? That'll run faster than using `np.vectorize`.

Comment: And I'm not at a computer to test it out right now, but I'm guessing it's converting to an `int`. What's the `dtype` of the return?

Comment: pay attention to `otypes`  in the `vectorize` docs. And its performance disclaimer.

Comment: You could use `np.maximum(0, x)`.  That is already vectorized.

Comment: Yes @jared, this a common error of ignoring the `otypes` documentation.  As written it determines the dtype from the first calculation, which for a `0` is `int`.

Answer (score 2):

As @jared comments, it's best to define the vectorized function directly, e.g.

```py
def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(x, 0)
```

Comment: Or just use `np.max`.

Comment: Actually, you would use `np.maximum` (the function with two operands).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited the answer to show your simpler suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It's dangerous to use `np.vectorize` without actually reading the docs.  In this case you ignored the bit about how it determines the output `dtype`.  By default it does a trial calculation, and uses the result to determine the dtype.  With `[0,0,.5,1]` the result of the first term is `0`, an int.  So all the terms will be int.  If you want a float result, ensure the first return is a float, or use the `otypes` parameter to set it explicitly.

`vectorize` is not a speed tool.  For one argument, and a 1d one at that, the list comprehension is simpler and just as good.

```
In [154]: def relu_activation(x):
     ...:     return max(0,x)
     ...: relu = np.vectorize(relu_activation)
     ...: 
     ...: z = np.array([0,0,0.5,1])
     ...: z = relu(z)
```

Note the dtype of this result - integer:

```
In [155]: z
Out[155]: array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Give it a float as first value - and get float result:

```
In [156]: relu([.5,0,0,1,.25])
Out[156]: array([0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.25])
```

Specify otypes:

```
In [157]: relu = np.vectorize(relu_activation, otypes=[float])    
In [158]: relu([0,0,.5,1])
Out[158]: array([0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. ])
```

Or to make things more list like, object dtype:

```
In [159]: relu = np.vectorize(relu_activation, otypes=[object])    
In [160]: relu([0,0,.5,1])
Out[160]: array([0, 0, 0.5, 1], dtype=object)
```

Or tweak the function, so it always returns a float

```
In [161]: def relu_activation(x):
     ...:     return max(0.0,x)
     ...: relu = np.vectorize(relu_activation)
     ...: 
     ...: z = np.array([0,0,0.5,1])
     ...: z = relu(z)
In [162]: z
Out[162]: array([0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. ])
```

For a function as simple as this, `vectorize` isn't needed.  While it has it uses, it's too easy for beginners to use it because they don't know enough `numpy`.  If you must iterate, don't be afraid of sticking with the list comprehension.